# Necessary conditions for convergence of matrix series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I am interested in necessary conditions under which the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n \Omega (A^n)^{\top}$$

converges wrt. a submultiplicative matrix norm, where A is diagonalizable and $\Omega$ is positive definite. I believe that the eigenvalues of A must be strictly less than 1, but I am failing to find a reason why.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Please note that askers are generally expected to provide [some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to their question besides the question-statement itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the eigenvalues of $A$ are strictly less than $1$, then we have
$$
\left\|\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n \Omega A^{nT}\right\| \leq 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|A^n\| \|\Omega\| \|A^{Tn}\|
$$
which converges, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\|\Omega\| \|A^{n}\|\|A^{nT}\|)^{1/n} = \rho(A) \rho(A^T) = \rho(A)^2$, where $\rho$ denotes the spectral radius.

On the other hand, if $x$ is a (possibly complex) eigenvector of $A^T = A^*$ with an eigenvalue $\lambda$, with $|\lambda| \geq 1$, then the series
$$
x^*\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n \Omega A^{nT}\right)x = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bar \lambda^n x^*\Omega \lambda^n x = 
(x^*Ax) \sum_{n=0}^\infty |\lambda|^{2n}
$$
fails to converge.  Here, $A^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose of $A$.

Both of these apply whether or not $A$ is diagonalizable.